# while read 2 times on shell script don’t work

Tags: sh

I'm working on a script and when I try to use the while read 2 times the first loop only work once.

```
un=$(echo $LOGNAME | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
grep -v '^#' nodeteste.txt > auxiliar.txt
while read line
do
  ssh "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo
  cut -d "," -f 1 arquivo.externo > arquivo.externo.cut
  uniq arquivo.externo.cut > arquivo.externo.cut.uniq
  while read line2
  do
   valor=$(grep -c "$line2 " arquivo.base)
   if [ $valor -eq 0 ]; then
     echo $line >> arquivo.base.diferente
     echo $line2 >> arquivo.base.diferente
     grep -i "$line2," arquivo.externo >> arquivo.base.diferente
     echo $line $line2 $valor "eh diferente"
   fi
  done < arquivo.externo.cut.uniq
done < auxiliar.txt
rm auxiliar.txt
```

I'm think I lose the stdin/out anytime but I’m stuck here, any ideas?

Comment: what is the content of your `auxiliar.txt` file?

Comment: auxiliar.txt receive the ip's from nodeteste.txt after a grep of comments, i use that to do a ssh for cat the files on other servers

Comment: Not what is it for, but what is its exact contents? Anyway, you have an answer below...

Comment: 100.1.1.1
100.1.1.2

Comment: The answer is to help you debug your own code.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening, in the loops, strip the script from all the unnecessary stuff:

```
while read line ; do
    echo "outer: $line"
    while read line2 ; do
        echo "inner $line2"
    done
done
```

When you run this, you'll get

```
test
outer: test
test
inner test
test
inner test
^Dtest
outer: test
test
inner test
^D^D
```

When you take the input from a file, it becomes different. For example: create a file `a`:

```
a
a
a
a
a
```

and a file `b`:

```
b
b
b
b
b
```

and do:

```
while read line ; do
    echo "outer: $line"
    while read line2 ; do
        echo "inner $line2"
    done <b
done <a
```

The result will be:

```
outer: a
inner b
inner b
inner b
inner b
inner b
```

and not 5x the outer circle.

A solution would be:

```
for line in $(<a) ; do 
    echo "outer: $line"
    for line2 in $(<b) ; do 
        echo "inner $line2"
    done
done 

outer: a
inner b
inner b
inner b
outer: a
inner b
inner b
inner b
outer: a
inner b
inner b
inner b
```

(I've made the `a` and `b` a bit shorter)

Comment: you dont add ssh on this, i belive the ssh is the problem but i dont no how to solve

Comment: The ssh should not be a problem. You are doing a `cat` of a file (`arquivo`) and that should not consume stdin, only produce stdout, which you redirect.

Comment: nice, you have an ideia how can i do to this 2 loops works?

Comment: added a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Here i found the problem, the ssh uses de stdin causing the 1 loop to only work once, when i use -n option the sdtin is redirect.

Problem source:

```
ssh "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo
```

Works source:

```
ssh -n "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo
```

SSH Manual:
-n        Redirects stdin from /dev/null (prevents reading stdin).